# Passing custom functions to jquery objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Please have few sec patience. js beginner. Thnx.
I am playing with boilerplate
https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/src/jquery.boilerplate.js

inside of it I added 2 new functions

```
   init: function () {

      this.mynewFunction2();
   },

    mynewFunction1: function (){

      console.log('ok');
    },

    mynewFunction2: function (){

       $('.link').click(function(){
             this.mynewFunction1();
       });
    }
```

you probably already see the problem but the question is how do I pass my mynewFunction1  to jquery object ?
I did find few posts where they say that I need to assign my new function in order to be called inside jquery object but I am bit lost there. So if you have a spare minute could you please post an example based on my code above. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new function creates a new scope, which in turn creates a new `this`:

```
mynewFunction2: function (){
   $('.link').click(function(){
         this.style.color = 'red';
         // this inside the event handler is the clicked element
   });
}
```

You can just drop the anonymous function and pass it directly:

```
mynewFunction2: function (){
   $('.link').click(this.mynewFunction1);
}
```

or if you have to pass parameters:

```
mynewFunction2: function (){
   var that = this; // references the parent object
   $('.link').click(function() {
      that.mynewFunction1(this); // passes the clicked element
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 mynewFunction2: function (){
      var self = this;
       $('.link').click(function(){
             self.mynewFunction1();
       });
    }
```

Comment: +1 because you're right, but would you care to explain to the OP why this works?

Comment: thnx nnnnn, yes a further insight would be great.

Comment: It is kinda like javascript automagically sets a new `var this = ""context"";` inside the function declaration, overriding the previous declaration. To understand this you must understand js variable scope first. It is not a 2 paragraph explanation; check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword